# Using class mixin causes Pycharm to say "unexpected argument" for null=True

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm, mixins

Pycharm shows "unexpected argument" when I use `CIEmailField(null=True)`, but not when I use `CIEmailFieldOld(null=True)`. `null` is still a valid argument as far as I can tell, so why is Pycharm giving me this warning?

```
from django.db.models import *

class CIText:
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'citext'

class CIEmailField(CIText, EmailField):
    pass

class CIEmailFieldOld(EmailField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'citext'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with Pycharm and the inheritance chain. If you follow the inheritance of EmailField, you will come to the class RegisterLookupMixin. Removing the RegisterLookupMixin super class from the class Field will get rid of the Pycharm syntax error.

Comment: I just tried this, it works. `CIEmailField` is actually part of Django's source code: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/fields/citext/ So would this be considered a bug (affects functionality), or is it something trivial?

Comment: In other words, since the `CIText` mixin doesn't have a `__init__`, then the init from `EmailField` should still be in effect (nothing overwrote it), so none of this really matters except for the IDE, right?

Comment: You are correct, its not a bug. I misread your original code. This seems to be a problem with pycharm.